# Should I manipulate DOM directly or using React state/props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the situation:

This component renders many data as a list. If I use React state/props to control the DOM style(add classes or modify some attributes), React will always run the `render()` function when user reacts with the list, like `mouseover`, `click` and etc..

Though React has virtual DOM technology, but I think it is still very inefficient to run `render()` every time. The documents do not recommend to manipulate DOM directly, but I think it is more efficient. What should I do? Thx.

Comment: Follow the recommendations in the documentation (don't manipulate the DOM directly unless you need to). In other words, follow best practices _now_ and if something starts to seem slow or inefficient _later_ then worry about it _then_.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency until you have a bottleneck. This is referred to as a "premature optimization" and it's a bad habit. React is more than fast enough to update the DOM at 60fps. Do not mutate the DOM that react outputs, ever.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mix writing React with directly manipulating the DOM; do either but not both.

If you are already using React, just use it for what you want. If possible, break the components into as small of pieces as possible; this will help the number renders.

It may be slightly more inefficient to have React re-render too much, but remember that React has been heavily optimized for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as rerendering in `react` is concerned, it has been heavily optimised. You may think that the `render()` function runs on every small manipulation but the thing that is not visibile is that the `rerender` doesn't occur for the entire DOM rather on only the portion that has changed.

React uses the `virtual DOM technology` and then it takes out the difference between the current and the virtual dom much like string comparison and then only renders the difference and is thus highly efficient.

So I would recommend you to follow the documentation and not mix DOM manipulation with react.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho It seem like react is rerendering a lot. React is still much faster than manipulating the real dom