# How to wait and fade an element out?

Tags: reactjs

I have an alert box to confirm that the user has successfully subscribed:

```
<div className="alert alert-success">
    <strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for subscribing!
</div>
```

When a user sends an email, I'm changing the "subscribed" state to true.

What I want is to:

- Show the alert box when the subscribed state is true
- Wait for 2 seconds
- Make it fade out

How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

May 2021 update: as tolga and Alexey Nikonov correctly noted in their answers, it’s possible to give away control over how long the alert is being shown (in the original question, 2 seconds) to the `transition-delay` property and a smart component state management based on the [`transitionend` DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event). Also, [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are these days recommended to handle component’s internal state, not [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). So I updated my answer a bit:

```
function App(props) {
  const [isShowingAlert, setShowingAlert] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
      <div>
        <div
          className={`alert alert-success ${isShowingAlert ? 'alert-shown' : 'alert-hidden'}`}
          onTransitionEnd={() => setShowingAlert(false)}
        >
          <strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for subscribing!
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => setShowingAlert(true)}>
          Show alert
        </button>
        (and other children)
      </div>
    );
}
```

The delay is then specified in the `alert-hidden` class in CSS:

```
.alert-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 250ms linear 2s; // <- the last value defines transition-delay
}
```

The actual change of `isShowingAlert` is, in fact, near-instant: from false to true, then immediately from true to false. But because the transition to opacity: 0 is delayed by 2 seconds, the user sees the message for this duration.

Feel free to play around with [Codepen with this example](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/BaWzLdX).

---

Since React renders data into DOM, you need to keep a variable that first has one value, and then another, so that the message is first shown and then hidden. You could remove the DOM element directly with jQuery's `fadeOut`, but [manipulating DOM can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435734/should-i-manipulate-dom-directly-or-using-react-state-props).

So, the idea is, you have a certain property that can have one of two values. The closest implementation is a boolean. Since a message box is always in DOM, it's a child of some element. In React, an element is result of rendering a component, and so when you render a component, it can have as many children as you want. So you could add a message box to it.

Next, this component has to have a certain property that you can easily change and be completely sure that, as soon as you change it, the component gets re-rendered with new data. It's component state!

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showingAlert: false
    };
  }
  
  handleClickShowAlert() {
    this.setState({
      showingAlert: true
    });
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        showingAlert: false
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`alert alert-success ${this.state.showingAlert ? 'alert-shown' : 'alert-hidden'}`}>
          <strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for subscribing!
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickShowAlert.bind(this)}>
          Show alert
        </button>
        (and other children)
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, you can see that, for message box, either `alert-shown` or `alert-hidden` classname is set, depending on the value (truthiness) of `showingAlert` property of component state. You can then use [`transition` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to make hiding/showing appearance smooth.

So, instead of waiting for the user to click button to show the message box, you need to update component state on a certain event, obviously.

That should be good to start with. Next, try to play around with CSS transitions, `display` and `height` CSS properties of the message box, to see how it behaves and if the smooth transition happening in these cases.

Good luck!

PS. See [a Codepen for that](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/BWRzGB).

Comment: Great solution! I started using Semantic UI React recently and they have a component for this; I set it up with a visibility state and a timeout as above and it works great: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THING APPROACH: using Timeout is an Antipatern**. Instead use generic ***Transition*** Because you may not know the duration set as Fade-In/Out transition (for example in Bootstrap)

Comment: Hey Alexey Nikonov, thanks a lot for your suggestion! I think your idea works way better because the control over the alert’s state of being shown or hidden stays within one place, the transition-delay style property of the CSS class responsible for hiding it. I updated my answer with a new example.

Comment: This is brilliant :) Thanks

Answer (score 9):

### The correct way is to use Transition handler for Fade-in/out

In ReactJS there is [synthetic event](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#transition-events) to wait till fade-out is finished: ***onTransitionEnd***.

*NOTE* there are different css effects associated with different handlers. Fade is a Transition not an Animation effect.

Here is my example:

```
const Backdrop = () => {
  const {isDropped, hideIt} = useContext(BackdropContext);
  const [isShown, setState] = useState(true);
  const removeItFromDOM = () => {
    debugger
    setState(false)
  };
  return isShown
    ? <div className={`modal-backdrop ${isDropped ? 'show' : ''} fade` } onClick={hideIt} onTransitionEnd={removeItFromDOM}/>
    : null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An other way is to solve this with a CSS3 transition. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_animation_fade_out.htm

You can add a new class to the alert (like .hidden) and then you can relate .hidden with the class you defined for the alert.

```
alert.hidden{
    // Here you can define a css transition
}
```

In this solution you don't have to add a setInterval or anything, since css3 transitions already process it on browser render.