# cant save canvas to image - tainted canvas - react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

After line with `canvas.toDataURL()` I get an error with

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': tainted canvas
>   may no be exported

Tried to search solution at my own, with cross origin, but this didn't help me. Is there any possibility to download image created on canvas? I saw examples with `toDataURL()`, but those unfortunately don't work for me. I will consider other solutions.

```js
   _handleSaveButton(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('memesCanvas');
    console.log(canvas);
    
    var canvasimage=document.createElement("img");
    canvasimage.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
    canvasimage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    canvasimage.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
    alert(canvasimage);
  }
 
 <ReactButton onClick={() => this._handleSaveButton()} styleName={'generate-meme'} name='generate meme'/>
```

Comment: canvasimage.crossOrigin = '*'; doesn't help too

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)?

Comment: Are you using [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) anywhere?  How are you loading the image that you are providing to `drawImage()`?  Is it over the `file://` protocol?  Is the image on a different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this for a code challenge not too long ago. Not sure if this is exactly what you need but I hope it helps.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Save extends Component{
  saveCanvas() {
    const canvasSave = document.getElementById('resetCanvas');
    const d = canvasSave.toDataURL('image/png');
    const w = window.open('about:blank', 'image from canvas');
    w.document.write("<img src='"+d+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
    console.log('Saved!');
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.saveCanvas }>Save</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Save;
```

Comment: thanks for help, btw i dont know why but just window.open return error - with 'about:blank' - no error at all :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: You should under no circumstances manipulate the DOM.
Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435734/should-i-manipulate-dom-directly-or-using-react-state-props